# QtWebkit support for CSS and Javascript

Tags: qt, qtwebkit

We are planning to use Qtwebkit for Help viewer in our application, we need to support HTML 4.0, CSS and Javascript at the least. Just wondering if its a good option to use. Is it like a browser when we refer to Qt Webtool kit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation:

> QtWebKit provides facilities for rendering of HyperText Markup Language (HTML), Extensible HyperText Markup Language (XHTML) and Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) documents, styled using Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) and scripted with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Qt's HTML/CSS support is more than adequate for a Help viewer. I've had some good experience with the Qt Javascript engine too. Go for it.